# Using -like operator with two arrays

Tags: arrays, powershell, comparison, powershell-5.0

I have a question regarding the `-like` operator in PowerShell.

Script written in

```
PSVersion                      5.0.10240.17146
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                   10.0.10011.16384
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
```

I have the following variable.

```
$ProgramVar
```

This variable can contain Example;

```
Microsoft VisualStudio JavaScript Project System
Java 7 Update 80
Java 8 Update 111
Microsoft VisualStudio JavaScript Language Service
Java Auto Updater
```

I have another variable called $Exclusions

```
$Exclusions = @("*Microsoft Corporation*","*Microsoft*","*SAP BusinessObjects*","*Hewlett-Packard*","*JavaCard*","*Development*")
```

I need to compare each $program in $ProgramVar and see if the $program -like any $exclusion. I've written it several different ways but i cannot figure out the correct way. I've deleted most of what i've tried but here's where i'm currently at..

```
foreach($instance in $Programvar)
{

    if($instance -eq $Null) #<---- Dummy Check.
    {
        Write-Host "I is blank"
    }
    else
    {
        foreach($ex in $Exclusions)
        {
            #$count = 0
            #$exclusion = $Exclusions.Get($count)
            if($instance -like $ex)
            {
                Write-Host "A substring in $instance matches $ex.. Removing from array "                     
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host "$instance does not contain $ex Substring"
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I think this will work but haven't fully tested it. I would like to know if there is more cleaner or quicker way.

EDIT:

Props to JPBlanc for answering my question. I have gone through and made it a little easier to read. Here's what i ended up with so that others can easily implement the code. JPBlanc's solution will work, but like i said, i like it to be a little verbose so i can see what it's doing.

```
    $ExclusionTester = $Programvar | % `
    {
        Write-Host "Testing Exclusions: $Exclusions"
        Write-Host "$programvar"
        $ExclusionsExtracted=@() #<--- Blank array
    }`
    {
        $Program=$_; $Exclusions | % `
            {

                if ($Program -like $_) #<---- $_ Current exclusion
                    { 
                        $ExclusionsExtracted +=$Program #<---- Adding exclusion to array
                        write-host "A substring in $Program Matches $_" -ForegroundColor green
                        Write-Host "Removing $Program from ProgramVar array" -ForegroundColor Cyan
                    }

                    #Uncomment the below line to possibly rebun?
                    <#
                    else
                    {
                        Write-Host "No Substring in $t Matches $_" -ForegroundColor Yellow
                    } #>
            }
    }`
    {
        $ExclusionsExtracted #<---- End result after testing.
        $programvar = $programvar | where {$ExclusionsExtracted -notcontains $_}
    }
```

Thanks again

Comment: have you checked -contains operator ?

Comment: @Abhijithpk -Contains is not for partial/wildcard matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the fact that $a contains the strings and $e contains the exclusions :

```
$a = "Microsoft VisualStudio JavaScript Project System","Java 7 Update 80","Java 8 Update 111","Microsoft VisualStudio JavaScript Language Service","Java Auto Updater"
$e = "*Microsoft Corporation*","*Microsoft*","*SAP BusinessObjects*","*Hewlett-Packard*","*JavaCard*","*Development*"
```

This one liner gives the strings to exclude :

```
$a | % {$r=@()}{$t=$_; $e | % {if ($t -like $_){$r+=$t}}}{$r}
```

$r : a tab of string to exclude (the return value).

$t : a temp var conttaining currentstring to evaluate.

At the end you can get a new tab :

```
$tabres = $a | where {$r -notcontains $_}
```

Comment: can you explain the {$r=@()} and the {$r} parts of the one liner. I'm interested in what the "single" {}-parenthesize do. Thanks

Comment: These are part of the Foreach-Object syntax `{$r=@()}` is a begin scriptblock (script block to run before processing any input objects). `{$r}` is a end scriptblock (a script block to run after processing all input objects).

Comment: ok, but how does it work with variables? I thought that variables in a scriptblock only exist in the scriptblock scope.

Comment: You're rigth, but here all the content of the 3 scriptblocks are played in the same scope.

Comment: That's great. It excludes what i'm doing but i'd like for it to be a little more verbal about it. I'll play around with it and see what i come up with. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

try Something like this

```
$ProgramVar = "Microsoft VisualStudio JavaScript Project System","Java 7 Update 80","Java 8 Update 111","Microsoft VisualStudio JavaScript Language Service","Java Auto Updater"
$Exclusion = "*Microsoft Corporation*","*Microsoft*","*SAP BusinessObjects*","*Hewlett-Packard*","*JavaCard*","*Development*"

$ProgramVar | where {$Prog=$_; $Exclusion | where {$Prog -like $_ } }
```